# How do i return a quoted string from a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple of strings that i would want to extract the contents as a quoted string, i.e.

```
tup=('string1', 'string2', 'string3')

when i do this

main_str = ",".join(tup)

#i get

main_str = 'string1, string2, string3'

#I want the main_str to have something like this

main_str = '"string1", "string2", "string3"'
```

Gath

Comment: Do you care if the strings already have a quote in them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
", ".join('"{0}"'.format(i) for i in tup)
```

or

```
", ".join('"%s"' % i for i in tup)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one answer would be:

```
', '.join([repr(x) for x in tup])
```

or

```
repr(tup)[1:-1]
```

But that's not really nice. ;)

Updated:
Although, noted, you will not be able to control if resulting string starts with '" or '". If that matters, you need to be more explicit, like the other answers here are:

```
', '.join(['"%s"' % x for x in tup])
```

Comment: missing closing angled bracket

Comment: repr(x) should be used if the strings in tup might have quotes in them and you care (say, you want to retrieve what is in the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> t = ('s1', 's2', 's3')
>>> ", ".join( s.join(['"','"']) for s in t)
'"s1", "s2", "s3"'
```